# WP7 Live tile like People Hub or Me app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Can we create a Live tile like 'People Hub' or 'Me' app in wp7? I have already got the Flipping Style but I want an animating tile like 'People Hub' or 'Me'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with Windows Phone 7 - those types of tiles are limited to the built-in apps.